# Why people can't review my app at the app store from other country (Germany)?

Tags: ios, app-store

Today I received a message from a client that told me that 'they cannot review my app in the German AppStore'.

My app is based in Spain and is in Spanish & English. Does somebody know why they cannot review the app?

- Is because the language?
- Why only Germany?

Comment: can you please share the link of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing this: choosing a more unique nickname. I tried using my first name and the review would not submit, so I changed my nickname to my Apple ID and voilà, the review went through.The problem was that the nickname wasn't unique enough. How am I supposed to know which nicknames are taken?